# How to add additional include directories permanently in qt projects [visual studio 2013]?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5

I installed Qt5.5.1 (qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.5.1) and visual studio add-in 1.2.3 + some procedures on visual studio 2013

Now i am able to coding qt projects in visual studio 2013 and compile it.
if i want to get rid of references issue and have intellisense in my project:

[image]

each time i make a new qt project i should do :

in project properties (solution explorer) >c/c++ >additional include directories >edit
and add this directory : C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtANGLE

is there a way to do this permanently and for all  projects?

Comment: Try to open the menu Qt5 -> Qt Project Settings -> Qt Modules. Do you see the Angle module ? If yes, you can simply check it.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Bershov.no there is no checkable  Angle module in modules tab.what is next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a basic project with the required dependencies, and [save it as a Project Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.120).aspx).
(Do not forget to Build both Debug and Release configurations before exporting)

[image]

And then you can find your template here:

[image]